# Ruby on Rails - Sort Database Data and Then Edit Data Per Row According to Sorted Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, edit

Here's what I want to do:

1. Select all rows in the database table 'applicants' and then sort according to the column 'points' in descending order.
2. One by one, from top to bottom, edit the 'reservedIn' column of each row.

I'm using MySQLServer 5.5, using with it HeidiSQL. I'm also using Ruby 1.9.2, Rubygems 1.4.2 and I can't identify the Ruby on Rails version. I had it installed earlier this January.

Thank you!

**Update:**

Hello again! I've been studying what I've learned from the comments below and I came up with this (practice function, not final)! It's supposed to select all applicants, sorted in the order specified, and then change all their mNames into 'X'. It doesn't work! What's wrong? Can anyone tell?

```
def generateReservations
if !session[:user_id]
    redirect_to :controller =>'user', :action=> 'login'
else
    @applicants = Applicant.find(:all, :order => "points DESC, sName, fName, mName ")
    #respond_to do |applicant|
    @applicants.each do
    mName = 'X'
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Applicants.order("points DESC")`
2. I cant offer to add `link_to("Edit", edit_applicant_path(applicant))`

I your view, for example

```
<% Applicants.order("points DESC").each do |applicant| %>
   <%= applicant.title %> <%= link_to("Edit applicant", edit_applicant_path(applicant)) %>
<% end %>
```

Something like that

Comment: Um... Could you clear up number two? I'm not making anything out. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, thanks. How about if I want to do it automatically?

Say for example I have in my view a link to a generateReservations.html.erb. Now what I really want is a functionin my applicants_controller.rb to do steps 1 and 2.

Comment: If you want to change 'reservedIn' manually, you can, for ex., create a HTTP POST request near every applicant in view. For that you can create a method in applicants_controller.rb, lets say change_reservation, get data from `params` there and update applicant's attributes.

Comment: Wow... OK I'm learning! Um... How about if I want it to be done for all applicants at once. I mean one link that invokes a method to do steps 1 and 2 for all applicants.

How do I do that method?

Comment: Hmm. It will be too much complicated to do it for all applicant at once, i guess. if you dont want to use `Applicants.all.order("points DESC")` in the view, you can create a variable `@applicants = Applicants.all.order("points DESC")` in controller's method which displays ordered applicants. then use `@applicants.each do ...`

Comment: Nice! I've got the power! Thank you very much! :)

I may be back in a while, though, for some more questions. Thanks again!

Comment: In rails 3, you don't need the all keyword.  Also, you would usually set conditions before call ing all:  Applicants.order(..).all